# Saving file field as None but reflects empty string in the database

Tags: django

I'm trying to submit a form with a file field. There are instances when the file is not yet available so the user will have to submit the form without the file first.

My field now looks like this

```
file_attachment_pdf = models.FileField(blank= True,null = True, unique=True)
```

I'm able to save 1 record with blank fields. When adding the 2nd record with blank file upload, it doesn't work anymore since there is an existing record with the file value.

Upon checking, it's an empty string.

So I tried to override the clean function in models.py

```
def clean(self):

        if not self.file_attachment_doc:
            print('doc is blank, will tag as Null')
            self.file_attachment_doc = None
```

But for some reason, when I check in the DB it still stores as an empty string. (I'm using DB Browser for SQLite, it says the field of data is Text with 0 chars)

When I try to submit, here is the error that is returned to me

**File with this File attachment pdf already exists.**

If this question was already asked and answered before, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileField` store the file path as a `CharField`. For `CharField`, the `null=True` settings, equals to store empty string. That why you see empty string in your db. Your error come from the `unique=True` parameter. That means that you can store only one empty file for your model.
Plus the model `clean` method is called only if you user model form to save you instance. In all way, if the method is call or not, it don't make difference, the value stored would be always empty string
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#null